# Multiple AP of same SSID, network keeps switching from one AP to another

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

So my office has multiple AP which has same SSID. I want to connect to specific AP which is close to me, which results in better performance. Windows does not allow me to connect to specific AP so I NetSetMan to connect by MAC Address. But after 5 minutes or so after connecting my network switches to poor AP. I have to connect again by activating the profile. I dont want to do it repeatedly. How can I solve this? How can I automate the activation of profile every 5 minutes or so by script?

Comment: Check your wireless card under device manager. Look in the drivers settings for roaming settings/aggressiveness. Set it to a lower setting if you have the option.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf86l.jpg it has limited properties, do you think it might be driver problem

Comment: Well, it's most certainly the drivers that govern this behavior..

Comment: You may be fighting against your network. Enterprise class Wi-Fi networks often have features where the APs conspire to fake out the clients and try to force them to roam to other APs, for the sake of load balancing and trying to get 5GHz capable devices to always use 5GHz. You probably need to discuss these problems with your IT staff.

Comment: I think its drivers fault, nvm I managed to run a script which calls netsetman every 5 min which connects me to the required mac address AP. This seems a good temp solution.